# MATLAB: double numeric integration (very particular case)

Tags: matlab, numeric, handle, numerical-integration, integral

I need to calculate a double integral where the inner function depends on both x and y (I integrate it on y and one of the limit depends on x), then I integrate the remaining on x. This is an example of code:

```
f1=@(x,y) x.^2+y; %inner function to be integrated on y

f2=@(x) sqrt(x).*integral(@(y)f1(x,y),x,3); %second function, to be integrated on x

V = integral(@(x)f2(x),0,2) %final calculation
```

I don't think `integral2` could be used because of the form of the second function...

PS: I don't want to use symbolic functions

PPS: I know that this case could be solved by simple calculation on papar, but it's only a trivial case, what I need to do is way more complex

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like exactly the kind of thing you would want to solve symbolically. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I also tried to solve it symbolically, but the functions I need to integrate don't have a known primitive, so matlab can't solve it... please tell me if I'm wrong

Comment: Trying your code and googling the error gave me this http://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77733-integrating-over-integral-error-a-and-b-must-be-floating-point-scalars , which I guess solve your problem

Comment: @Noel Segura, that's a great answer, really! Nice solution, thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, google is your friend, use it more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathworks expected this problem while creating `integral2()` (after all, dependent bounds are not that uncommon), so they have a way to handle this case as well. I have selected another function to handle which is easier verified, but I assume you will not mind that much.

```
f1=@(x,y) (x.*y)/2; %inner function to be integrated on y
fy = @(x) 3-x; % Lower bound
V = integral2(f1,0,2,fy,3) %final calculation
```

More information on the "doc page" (`doc integral2` in MATLAB terminal), or [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html)

**Edit:**
In case you have an integral as

```
integral(g(x) * integral( x^2*y, y=f(x), y=y1 ), x=a, x=b)
```

where `f1 = integral( x^2*y, y=f(x), y=y1 )`, you can simplify as `f2 = g(x)*f1 = integral( g(x)*x^2*y, y=f(x), y=y1 )`.

Comment: Your example is quite different from what I asked. See how my second function (I mean f2) is defined: `sqrt(x)*integral(...)`. I don't want to integrate the whole expression on both variables, am I clear? However thank you, I hope there will be a solution...

Comment: @user3758182 No, you are not clear. What patrik describes here exactly matches with what you describe in the first line of your question. Now you are saying something else. The only thing is that patrik here uses a different example.

Comment: @Bernhard what I want to say is that I need to integrate on y a function that depends on both x and y (and one of the limit is x). Then I multiply this integral by sqrt(x) and I need to calculate the the integral on x. The function to be integrated on both x and y is "bigger", If you take a look at my code I think it will be clear, Patrik is using a different example that doesn't match my need

Comment: @user3758182 Why don't you just move `sqrt(x)` inside the integral, as it is constant in `y` anyhow?

Comment: @user3758182 I have edited the answer with some motivations. In case you have a variable `f(x)` kept outside the integral it would not matter. You can just move it inside the integral. In case you have a variable depending on `g(y)` or `h(x,y)` outside the integral you will get troubles anyway. The answer to this would be a function of `y` this will require some sophisticated thinking and strategy. This will never be possible to solve without working with this exact integral.

Comment: Ok, you're right! I just refused this answer becase I was tring to solve both the cases: `sqrt(x)+integral` and `sqrt(x)*integral`, but I can separate the two manually. PS: take a look at Noel Segura above, totally worth it! However, thank you!

Comment: @user3758182 Right, if of course possible to separate the integrals manually. It is a quite complicated detour since the only thing you need is an answer, but it is possible. Using `integral2()` you should have the same answer (within some margin). The reason I gave this solution was that this would relieve you from manually manipulating the equation. All you would have to do is to move `g(x)` inside the inner integral (the one where you integrate over `y`). For humans this is more complicated, but for a compute it is simpler. Do not treat the computer a human. This will complicate things.